# What is the tag [cmakelists-options] about?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Recently I’ve come across a question using the [cmakelists-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmakelists-options). I am a regular CMake user but have no idea what these two words should mean together. Unfortunately, the tag does not have any description.

I am aware of what CMakeLists(.txt) do, know about the [`option`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) command in CMake and about the options you can specify when calling the [`cmake`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmake) command.

However, I still cannot imagine what “cmakelists” in connection with “options” should mean. I also browsed the 13 [tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmakelists-options) but I could not find any connection among them beyond using CMake. Most of them don’t even mention the word “option”.

**Could anyone explain the tag (and fill the tag wiki)? Or should the tag be burninated?**

Comment: It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217470/in-clion-how-do-you-set-cmakelists-txt-option-values) is the source of the tag. I have pinged the asker in comments to weigh in

Comment: It's literally [CMake options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html) (options in cmake) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217470/in-clion-how-do-you-set-cmakelists-txt-option-values#comment106512730_60217470) - would support nuking it and just replacing it with [cmake]

Comment: To avoid confusion, it is better to use [the full *CMakeLists.txt*](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=CMakeLists) whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The specific question involves CLion, but the tag is not about CLion, it's about options in CMake - using either the `option()` or the `set()` command. I neglected setting it on additional relevant questions, but I'm just getting to it. I'm also untagging questions where this tag is inappropriate..

It's better to have this tag then for people to occasionally tag their questions about this with [cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake) and [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options), which does happen (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481647/cmake-if-else-with-option) before my retag).

I'll also fill the tag wiki. And - it might be a good idea to rename this [cmake-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake-options) (although that could be confused with the CMake binaries' command-line options).

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Having [cmake-options] would be better than the current state; it’d be even better without the trailing `s`, not contained in the command name. However, I’d prefer to use tags [cmake] and [options] together rather than creating a special tag, just like we don’t have tags for other CMake commands like [cmake-if], [cmake-file], [cmake-get_filename_components] and so on. Please do not retag questions of other users before the community point of view is clarified.

Comment: @Melebius: `[tag:options]` must be the most generic thing ever. It would likely be misused, like the unexplained cmakelists-options has - and that's if people even think of it, which they might not when they type in `cmake`.

Comment: I think that the most effective method is nucking options too.